# No content from REST-Service via jQuery Ajax with Phonegap

Tags: android, json, jquery, cordova

I'm doing my first steps with Phonegap, but not able to get any contents from my service.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
  $.support.cors = true;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: BaseUri + 'industries',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('bla');
        var html = [];
        $.each(msg || [], function(idx, industry) {
            html.push('<li>' + industry.Title + '</li>');
        });

        $('#lstIndustries').html(html.join(''));
    },
    error: function(xhr, msg, err) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(err);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
});
```

It always calls the error-function. When I change the contentType/dataType to text the success-function will be called, but the response is empty.

I added the following line to my `assets/www/config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? :)

Comment: Are you testing from a browser or with in an android emulator?

Comment: Android emulator (4.2.2)

Comment: Can you check the jQuery mobile code on computer browser. Enable cors in chrome or firefox and remove the Phonegap part? Check the console for errors. That way we can check the specific error if any.

Comment: As mentioned below, when running the script in my browser I get the correct response from the service.
But there's an additonal OPTIONS-request to the URI, which is not allowed by the service. But this should'nt be the problem, because I get a status 200 from the server, after performing the GET-requet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the dataType to 'jsonp'?  Due to security restrictions in browsers, you have to specify to use jsonp or add a callback=? to your json call.  So either of these two methods:

jsonp:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

callback method:

```
url: BaseUri + 'industries&callback=?',
dataType: 'json'
```

Also for cors to work I think this needs to be enabled on the server you are getting the data from as well.

You may also want to try and see if you can get the data in the browser without waiting for onDeviceReady, which will only fire when viewing on your device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh, you were right. I had to configure the IIS first. When I now open the index.html in my browser (without waiting for onDeviceReady) I get the response I'm looking for. But when I'm trying the same within the emulator (with waiting for onDeviceReady) I'm having the same problem as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried had similar problems when developing. I had to have the following when working with the emulator in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="http://10.0.2.2" subdomains="true"/>
```

Also try testing the API straight from a browser to see its the API that is the problem or the emulator